# Limit Access Query By Date

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to run a query in Access that would return all the records created in the current month and the previous month. Selecting the table and the fields is not the issue. In this particular query the field to limit the query is ReleaseDate and has the value of Date/Time. This query would have to take in account that the previous month may be in the previous year when the current month is January.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DateSerial()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dateserial-function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503) to determine the start and end of your target date range.

For example, the start of the previous month from today (4/19/2021) ...

```vb
? DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) -1, 1)
3/1/2021
```

And the first of next month ...

```vb
? DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) +1, 1)
5/1/2021
```

So you could apply those conditions to `ReleaseDate` in your query's `WHERE` clause  like this ...

```sql
WHERE ReleaseDate >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) -1, 1)
  And ReleaseDate  < DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) +1, 1)
```

Note that `DateSerial()` will adjust the year part of its output date when you give it a month value less than 1 or greater than 12 ...

```vb
? DateSerial(2021, 0, 1)
12/1/2020
```